# Why My string . Find is not avalible

Tags: c#

I am using Visual studio 2010.
I need to replace some part of my string, thus I should find the specific charter in my string. 
but `.find` is not available for me.
What should I do, is there any specific library for that?

```
string selected="ddddtttjjj";
selected.find("t");
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: I already did read that but there was not any help

Comment: please explain "but .find is not available in for me" ... do you #include <string>?

Comment: I have add 'using System.Text'

Comment: I did not find any System.string or basic_string

Comment: im confused. you are labeled this post as c++ no as c#... are you using c++ o c#

Comment: Perhaps I should use Indexof In c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C#, String.IndexOf

```
string str = "abcdefg";
var ix = str.IndexOf("d");
Console.WriteLine("Ix=" + ix);
// output 
//Ix=3
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx

but, if you want to repleace a substring you can use. "String.Replace"

```
string str = "abcdefg";
str = str.Replace("d","xDx");
Console.WriteLine(str);
// ouput
// abcxDxefg
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

**note that String.Replace Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string.**

Comment: Thx for your answer. What if I need second occurrences of "d"

Comment: all ocurrences will be replaced

Comment: there Is especial issue I have Lots of zeros for examples, (I am writing a table to text file). I don't want some of them, I need to have access to which one to erase or replace with "";

Comment: the statement 'Replace("0","")' will replace all for nothing. in other cases thats depends on how you decide which zeroes you want to be replaced. May be you want replace "00",'" so keeping the alone zeros. just experiment.